# how do i pass url parameter after page name in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a page url **localhost://testing/partners**, here i need to pass parameters after page name like. **localhost://testing/partners/category/abcd** or **localhost://testing/partners/details/xyz**
but when i am adding parameter after page name getting error 404 page not found.

and also i need to fetch that parameters. i have tried but its not working.

```
 add_rewrite_rule( '^partners/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?pagename=partners&$matches[1]', 'top' );
```

Answer (score 2):

@initial

If you are trying to create post names for custom categories, you can make these changes in the Permalink Settings from the WordPress Dashboard.

Settings->Permalinks

[image]

Reference:

https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/settings-permalinks-screen/

Comment: parameter can be any thing not just category. when i update custom structure not working showing page not found.
ex - https://localhost/testing/pagename/abcxyz